# Filter visual using containstring function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I don't understand the error message or the logic behind this code.

I got 2 tables:

1- Services[service] which has the list of services.

[image]

2- 'Cloud ops'[Services] which has the services impacted per incident

[image]

In the Cloud ops table, we may have incidents impacting more than one service. EX: in the cloud ops services field we can find something like this:

> Exchange 2016 (S14) Exchange 2019 (S19)

I have a slicer with Services[service] list.

My objective is to filter My Clou ops table using the selection made in the slicer. If I chose only Exchange 2019 in the Slicer, all the items containing Exchange 2019 would be shown. even if it has a additional service such as the example above.

I tryed to use DAX for this and I don't get why this isn't working.

```
  findServices = 
        FILTER('Cloud Ops',
             CONTAINSSTRING('Cloud Ops'[Services],Services[Service])
            )
        )
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this even the right path to reach my goal?

Thanks for the support.